# UIView under Navigation Bar after full screen

Tags: ios, swift, navigationbar

I have an application with a navigation bar.
When I click on a photo preview in my application, it displays the photo in full screen. But when I close the full screen, the view of my controller is under the navigation bar.

I saw on StackOverflow that it was necessary to add this line:

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = []
```

It works but it creates another bug.
So I would like to know if there was another alternative?

**UPDATE :**

[image]

Comment: What other bug does it create? Anyway, as of iOS 7 that is the default layout of iOS apps: a UIViewController's view extends under the navigation bar, but you can control that using the layout edges and other properties.

Comment: How the constraints of view in question are set?

Comment: Before posting the previews of the photos, I display a loader that I made manually. And by adding this line of code, the loader is shifted.

Answer (score 0):

1- Make your navigation bar opaque.

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
```

2- If you are using Xib then check “Safe Area Layout Guides” in the File Inspector as shown below.
[image]

3- And if you want to do it programmatically then after adding on view

```
self.yourView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
if (@available(iOS 11, *)) {
    UILayoutGuide * guide = self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide;
    [self.yourView.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:guide.leadingAnchor].active = YES;
    [self.yourView.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:guide.trailingAnchor].active = YES;
    [self.yourView.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:guide.topAnchor].active = YES;
    [self.yourView.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:guide.bottomAnchor].active = YES;
}
```